# Is it possible to embed ActiveMQ like instance in Mulesoft

Tags: java, spring, mule-studio

I would like to embed Active-MQ broker into Mule flow. I have read that the messages are saved into the file (KahaDB). I read the book "Active-MQ in action" and so I have used "Embedding ActiveMQ using Spring" and I have configured by Using the BrokerFactoryBean:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean"
        id="broker">
        <spring:property value="classpath:activemq.xml" name="config" />
        <spring:property value="true" name="start" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

(Add the library Activemq-all-5.8.0.jar)

And the configuration file is activemq.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost">
        <!-- Destination specific policies using destination names or wildcards -->
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" memoryLimit="50mb"/>
                    <policyEntry topic=">" memoryLimit="50mb"/>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
        <!-- Use the following to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in JMX -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>
        <!-- The store and forward broker networks ActiveMQ will listen to -->
        <networkConnectors>
            <!-- by default just auto discover the other brokers -->
            <networkConnector name="default-nc" uri="multicast://default"/>
            <!-- Example of a static configuration:
            <networkConnector name="host1 and host2" uri="static://(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)"/>
            -->
        </networkConnectors>
        <!-- KahaDB definition -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="{user.dir}/activemq-data/KahaDB" />
        </persistenceAdapter>
        <!--  The maximum about of space the broker will use before slowing down producers -->
        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="200 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="10 gb" name="foo"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="1000 mb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
        <!-- The transport connectors ActiveMQ will listen to -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
```

The questions are:

1) I have the flow with JMS, how to visualize with web interface the messages in the tail? Is it possible to visualize the queue from web interface, like when the broken url is tcp://localhost:61616 (URL used to connect to the JMS Server) Active-MQ ?

2) I would like to store the messages into DB from the MULE console, is it possible?